# Audio mute-unmute icon

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to make an icon that lets you mute or unmute. The icon itself works, but the audio doesn't play. Here's the code:

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg/1200px-Mute_Icon.svg.png" 
            style="height: 80px; width: 80px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
</p>
<script language="javascript">
    
function changeImage() {
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/unmute-512.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg/1200px-Mute_Icon.svg.png";
             x.play();
 }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/unmute-512.png";
        x.pause();
}
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?

(also yes I am using w3schools's sounds)

Comment: `myaudio` and `myAudio` do not match for ids.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh that makes more sense lol. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x.muted is solution:

```js
function changeImage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    if (
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src ==
        "https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/unmute-512.png"
    ) {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src =
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg/1200px-Mute_Icon.svg.png";
        
        x.muted = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src =
            "https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/unmute-512.png";
        
        
        x.muted = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<audio id="myaudio" controls loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<img src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/unmute-512.png" 
            style="height: 80px; width: 80px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />
</p>
```